# Sequelize fn ARRAY_AGG with DISTINCT

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a sequelize query, where I'd like to retrieve the unique values of a associated field

Example Models

```
const Owner = sequelize.define('owner', 
  {
   name: DataTypes.STRING,
   ...
  }
)

const Car = sequelize.define('car', {
  year: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  ...
})

Owner.hasMany(Car);
Car.belongsTo(Owner);
```

Wanted query output:

```
{
  name: 'Marc',
  ... 
  car_years: [
    1995,
    2001,
    2005
  ]
}

// Marc has at least three cars which year attribute is 1999 or 2001 or 2005 (duplicate years are ommited / DISTINCT)
```

So I tried

```
const owners = await Owner.findAll(
{
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [
        sequelize.fn('ARRAY_AGG', sequelize.col('cars.year')),
        'car_years',
      ],
    ],
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: Car,
      attributes: [],
    },
  ],
  group: [sequelize.col('owner.id')],
}
)
```

This works, but I get duplicated years in my array.
I tried using

```
sequlize.fn(DISTINCT, ...)
```

which I often found in other stackoverflow answers, but it errors out with

```
syntax error at or near DISTINCT
```

So my question is: how do I get DISTINCT in there to get unique values only?

**using sequelize v6 and postgres v12**

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I was having the same issue and just figured out a solution.

If anyone else is having this issue, Switch to using `sequelize.literal` instead of `sequelize.fn` and write your own select statement.

In this scenario change `sequelize.fn('ARRAY_AGG', sequelize.col('cars.year')),` to `sequelize.literal('array_agg(DISTINCT "cars"."year") as years')`